# sonar failed to detect a major issue 'Sections of Code should not be "commented out"'

Tags: sonarqube

I noticed one bug in SonarQube.
In Rule: 'Sections of Code should not be "commented out"'

When I add a trailing comma at the end the the sonar is not detecting this and giving no error. Is anything I can do here?

Answer (score 2):

Implementations of this rule use heuristics. Apparently when you added the comma, it tipped over in the heuristic's eyes from being code to non-code text.

To make sure the commented-out code is picked up again, make it less text-y. I.e. remove the non-code characters such as ','.

Comment: Thanks But In our organization, developers bypassing this rule by adding comma(,) on commented codeline before committing code. Any solution for this?